# javascript formatted date

Tags: javascript

Let say date current date is 10 Jan 2011. When I get date using js code

```
var now = new Date();
var currentDate = now.getDate() + '-' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + now.getFullYear();
```

It reutrns "10-1-2011"
but I want "10-01-2011" (2 places format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var now = new Date();
alert((now .getMonth() < 9 ? '0' : '') + (now .getMonth() + 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice short way:

```
('0' + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
```

So:

```
var currentDate = now.getDate() + '-' + ('0' + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + now.getFullYear();
```

- `(now.getMonth() + 1)` adjust the month
- `'0' +` prepends a "0" resulting in "01" or "012" for example
- `.slice(-2)` slice off the last 2 characters resulting in "01" or "12"

Answer (score 1):

```
function leftPad(text, length, padding) {
  padding = padding || "0";
  text = text + "";
  var diff = length - text.length;
  if (diff > 0)
     for (;diff--;) text = padding + text;
  return text;
}

var now = new Date();

var currentDate = leftPad(now.getDate(), 2) + '-' + leftPad(now.getMonth() + 1, 2js) + '-' + now.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

the quick and nasty method:

```
var now = new Date();
var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
var currentDate = now.getDate() + '-' + (month < 10 ? '0' + month : month) + '-' + now.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var now = new Date();
now.format("dd-mm-yyyy");
```

would give 10-01-2011